# laravel relationship throw non object error

Tags: php, laravel

I have `ContactForm` model that is belongs to `IssueCat` model. this relationship is defined in model like so:

```
class ContactForm extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function issue_cat(){
        return $this->belongsTo('IssueCat');
    }

}

class IssueCat extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function contact_forms(){
        return $this->hasMany('ContactForm');
    }

}
```

When I query contact form using `$cf = ContactForm::findOrFail($id)`, the following script throw the error

```
$cf->issue_cat->issue_name
```

FYI, in ContactForm table i set foreign key of IssueCat to `issue_cat_id` which is resolve to `issue_cats.id`. what could be the problem, i am sure i missed something.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check for null before trying to use that dynamic property as an object. It can return null if the relationship doesn't exist in the database.

Check that the database record, for the current contact form model you are using, has the correct key set that corresponds to an existing IssueCat record.

You may want to rename those relations to camel case form as well.

```
public function issueCat() { ... }
```

The `getAttribute` method will look for a method that is the camel case form of the attribute you are trying to access.